# Random generator & CUDA

Tags: random, cuda

I have a question regarding the random generators in CUDA . I am using Curand to generate random numbers with the following code:

```
__device__ float priceValue(int threadid){

    unsigned int seed = threadid ;
    curandState s;
    curand_init (seed , 0, 0, &s);

    float randomWalk = 2;
    while (abs(randomWalk)> 1) {
        randomWalk = curand_normal(&s);
    }
    return randomWalk; 
}
```

I have tried to relaunch this code many times, I have always the same output. I could not find what’s wrong in this code. The threads give the same Ids but the curand_normal functions should change at each launching, right?

Comment: You start each thread with the same seed every time, its threadid. How can you expect the sequences to be different?

Comment: Actually I want to use the time to set a new seed each time but I am not sure about thi solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're running init each time you ask for a random value.  Instead you should run `curand_init()` once, in a separate kernel at the start of your code.  Then when you want a new random value, just call `curand_normal()`.  Then the values will change each time you call your device function.

For an example see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15247522/cuda-random-number-generation/15252202#15252202).

If you want to use time as a seed instead of thread ID, then pass [the value](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#time-function) returned by `clock()` or whatever is your favorite time function:

```
unsigned int seed = (unsigned int) clock64();
```

Comment: It would be great if curand_init() was callable from host. you are writing a whole function just to init curand!