# Generating Random Numbers with CUDA via rejection method. Performance problems

Tags: c++, optimization, random, cuda, mathematical-optimization

I'm running a Monte Carlo code for particle simulation, written in CUDA. Basically, in each step I calculate the velocity of each particle and update its position. The velocity is directly proportional to the path length. For a given material, the path length has a certain distribution. I know the probability density function of this path length. I now try to sample random numbers according to this function via [rejection method.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling) I would describe my CUDA knowledge as limited. I understood, that it is preferable to create large chunks of random numbers at once instead of multiple small chunks. However, for the rejection method, I generate only two random numbers, check a certain condition and repeat this procedure in the case of failure. Therefore I generate my random numbers on the kernel.

Using the profiler / nvvp I noticed, that basically 50% of my time is spend during the rejection method.

Here is my question: Are there any ways to optimize the rejection methods?

I appreciate every answer.

**CODE**

Here is the rejection method.

```
__global__ void rejectSamplePathlength(float* P, curandState* globalState,
    int numParticles, float sigma, int timestep,curandState state) {
int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
if (i < numParticles) {
    bool success = false;
    float p;
    float rho1, rho2;
    float a, b;
    a = 0.0;
    b = 10.0;
    curand_init(i, 0, 0, &state);
    while (!success) {
        rho1 = curand_uniform(&globalState[i]);
        rho2 = curand_uniform(&globalState[i]);
        if (rho2 < pathlength(a, b, rho1, sigma)) {
            p = a + rho1 * (b - a);
            success = true;
        }
    }
    P[i] = abs(p);

}
}
```

The *pathlength* function in the if statement computes a value y=f(x) on the kernel.
I"m pretty sure, that **curand_init** is problematic in terms of time, but without this statement, each kernel would generate the same numbers?

Comment: From these two posts you can get the answer you are seeking for: [Random generator & CUDA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297168/random-generator-cuda) and [Cuda Random Number Generation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15247522/cuda-random-number-generation/15252202#15252202).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could create a pool of random generated uniform variable in a previous kernel and then you pick your uniform in that pool and cycling over that pool. But it should be large enough to avoid infinite loop..

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be the selection of the realization, which the OP seems to have already solved, but the call of `curand_init` by each thread.