# Same random sequence in all threads

Tags: c++, random, cuda

For debugging purposes, I need to generate the same random sequence in all the threads of a given block using cuda random library, curand.

I tried with zero seed and zero sequence, with marsenne twister and xorwow, but I still get two different sequences if the block has different number of threads.

For example, with `curand_init(0, 0, 0, &state)` and one thread, I get two numbers:
0.442526 0.809567

with the same initialization code, but two threads, I get:
0.446065 0.730273

Given that I do not really care about the engine used for now, how can I get the same random sequence given the seed parameters and *independently from the number of threads* in that block?

Comment: Can you show your code? You're doing something wrong. Do you have individual state per thread?

Comment: Create your own poor random number generator (e. g. rand() { return (state += prime1)%prime2;  } I assume this is for simple testing.

Comment: In [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15247522/cuda-random-number-generation/15252202#15252202) I give a complete code for getting the same random sequence in each thread.